# Reading data in from a text file in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and I'm creating a java quiz game as a class project. My issue is in the game part of the program. I'm trying to read in the questions, answers, correct answer, and point values of each question from a text file using a for loop. My problem is I don't know how to write the code within the for loop to display the questions and answers and save the values of the correct answers and point values for the question. Here's the format in the text file:

```
Question
A) answer
B) answer
C) answer
D) answer
correct answer
point value
```

Here's my code:

```
//importing dialog box tools, scanner tools, and file reading/writing tools
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaQuiz
{
public static void main(String[],args) throws IOException
{
    //Declaring and initializing variables
    String userChoice, gameQuestion, gameAnswer;
    int gameScore = 0, menuChoice = 0;

    //Declaring file object
    File infile = new File("Questions.txt");

    //Declaring scanner object for file reading
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(infile);

    //Opening statement
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Let's Begin!");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "First Question!");

    //Reading data from "Questions.txt"
    for(int i=1; i<=7; i++) //there are 7 questions in the text file.
    {

    }

    //Closing file
    fileInput.close();
}
}
```

Comment: do you plan on displaying all the text through JOptionPanes?

Comment: Yea, displaying all text with dialogs is a terrible idea. Create an application window, then manipulate that as needed.

Comment: I'm new to the language, and I haven't gotten that far in the class to start using application windows. The only way I know how to display output is through the terminal or dialog boxes.

Answer (score 2):

Reading a file in Java is quite simple (at least, in Java 8). You can do this:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(PATHTOFILE));
Map<Character, String> answers = HashMap<>();

String question = lines.get(0);

answers.put('A', lines.get(1));
answers.put('B', lines.get(2));
answers.put('C', lines.get(3));
answers.put('D', lines.get(4));
Character answer = lines.get(5).charAt(0);

Integer value = Integer.parseInt(lines.get(6));
```

Then just have a function return an object, probably just a POJO, `Question` which holds all that information. Then you can use that question in your code.